# Hadoop's map join equivalent in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm looking for Hadoop's mapjoin equivalent in Spark and I could find this `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold`

1. Does it work fine with spark SQL ? I tried but it did not seem to have effect as shuffle read / write was same even if I apply the parameter or not.

I set this value and ran my query `sqlContext.sql("SET spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=100000000;")`

2. Is there any other equivalent concept in SPARK-SQL ?

Thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

1. This was introduced in Spark 1.1.0.
2. It *is* tested (a little bit) in the Spark test suite -- see [PlannerSuite](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/PlannerSuite.scala).
3. Your `SET` query is cheerfully and silently swallowed by versions of Spark that don't support it -- I just tried it with 1.0.2.

Comment: thanks... spark.sql.shuffle.partitions was also documented only in Spark 1.1.0 but works fine with Spark 1.0.1....

Comment: I'm saying something different here: the code implementing this feature is simply missing in the 1.0.0 branch, from which I presume 1.0.2 was released. I seems to have come with [this commit](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/c7db274be79f448fda566208946cb50958ea9b1a) about a week before the release of 1.0.2, but I see no evidence that it made it into that release (look at the last line of the large blue rectangle).

Comment: I see...thanks for the info...by any chance - you were able to check this feature in 1.1.0 ?

Comment: I haven't but I can. Do you have a simple experiment in mind?